# Reducing the size of flask app docker image

Tags: python, docker, pipenv

Good day, everyone. I'm attempting to optimize the flask app's image. Currently, the image is nearly 900 Mb in size, which is quite large. To reduce the number of layers, I tried combining some of the commands, but it didn't help that much. I'm curious if the Python dependencies have any bearing on the image size because I don't use that many 3rd party libraries inside. What else can be done to make the Dockerfile more optimized? Thanks for your advice.

```
FROM python:3.10-slim-buster AS base

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ARG CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
ARG BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE

ENV CI_COMMIT_BRANCH=${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y upgrade \
    && apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends \
        cron \
        git \
        ssh \
        wget \
    && apt-get autoremove -y \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN mkdir -p /var/log \
    && touch /var/log/cron.log

RUN pip install -U pip \
    && pip install pipenv

COPY ./Pipfile.lock /app/
WORKDIR /app/
RUN pipenv sync

ENV PATH="/app:${PATH}"

# copy at last to cache pipenv
COPY . /app/

ENTRYPOINT ["pipenv", "run"]

FROM base as import

RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "if [[ ${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH} == 'master' ]]; then crontab /app/crontab && rm /app/crontab; fi"]

CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "init.sh"]

FROM base AS flask_app

ENV FLASK_APP=flask_app.app
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST=flask_app
EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["flask", "run"]
```

This is the history of the image

```
IMAGE          CREATED       CREATED BY                                      SIZE      COMMENT
9753a26de321   6 days ago    /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["/bin/bash" "-c" "in…   0B        
68b646c479a8   6 days ago    /bin/sh -c crontab /app/crontab     && rm /a…   443B      
f8f249453b94   6 days ago    /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENTRYPOINT ["pipenv" "run…   0B        
a0b69c5ce801   6 days ago    /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY dir:8b886ennjkhvj2e04…   1.1MB     
07f535cb9b14   6 days ago    /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV PATH=/app:/usr/local/…   0B        
f525c7ab05f1   6 days ago    |1 DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive /bin/sh -c…   663MB     
4e5327dc3a19   6 days ago    /bin/sh -c #(nop) WORKDIR /app/                 0B        
8b547718f693   6 days ago    /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:3cb43d3313ef4e05…   54.6kB    
5e6f8d3fcba1   6 days ago    |1 DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive /bin/sh -c…   53.6MB    
d1c8e769c434   6 days ago    |1 DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive /bin/sh -c…   0B        
5684bb2cdc36   6 days ago    |1 DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive /bin/sh -c…   86.9MB    
a0778738690b   6 days ago    /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=nonin…   0B        
135abe4d83eb   2 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["python3"]              0B        
<missing>      2 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c set -ex;   savedAptMark="$(apt-ma…   9.49MB    
<missing>      2 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV PYTHON_GET_PIP_SHA256…   0B        
<missing>      2 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV PYTHON_GET_PIP_URL=ht…   0B        
<missing>      2 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV PYTHON_SETUPTOOLS_VER…   0B        
<missing>      2 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV PYTHON_PIP_VERSION=21…   0B        
<missing>      2 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c cd /usr/local/bin  && ln -s idle3…   32B       
<missing>      2 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c set -ex   && savedAptMark="$(apt-…   29.2MB    
<missing>      2 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV PYTHON_VERSION=3.10.0    0B        
<missing>      2 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV GPG_KEY=A0               0B        
<missing>      2 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c set -eux;  apt-get update;  apt-g…   7.06MB    
<missing>      2 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV LANG=C.UTF-8             0B        
<missing>      2 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV PATH=/usr/local/bin:/…   0B        
<missing>      2 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["bash"]                 0B        
<missing>      2 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:3cf72…               69.3MB
```

Comment: `RUN pipenv sync` adds 663MB, so I'd focus on that first. `apt-get -y upgrade` shouldn't be necessary if you use an updated base image. You can also use `python:3.10-alpine` as your base image. Alpine is more light-weight than Debian, but if you switch, you need to change from 'apt' to 'apk' which is Alpine's package manager.

Comment: Are `pipenv` itself and `git` necessary in your app?

Do you have a `.dockerignore` file?

Comment: Yes! In my project, I use git. I'm using the "slim-buster" version, which is nearly 40 megabytes in size, as a base image. Alpine image's size is 5 mb. The line 'apt-get -y upgrade' was removed, and the image's size was reduced to 945mb (it was 947mb). 'pipenv sync' simply installs the dependencies listed in the lock file. I have an ignore file in which I have listed all of the Byte-compiled, optimized, and DLL files.